# macOS - Get path to currently running application

Tags: macos, safari-extension

### Question

Is it possible to determine the location a macOS app was launched from at runtime?

### Context

I develop a Safari Extension, and in order for the extension to be enabled the application needs to be present `/Applications/`.  Several users have tried to run the application directly from the DMG file and then complained that the extension doesn't appear in Safari's extension settings.  I would like to detect this and alert them that they need to move the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `NSBundle`, specifically the `bundlePath` property. The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1407973-bundlepath?language=objc) says:

> The full pathname of the receiver’s bundle directory.

And you can use it something like this:

```
NSString* bundlePath;
bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]

NSLog(@"%@", bundlePath);
```

There's also `bundleURL` if you want a `NSURL` to work with instead of a string.

Comment: Thought it might be something like that. :+1: